# How do I allow my .net program to compile C# code while running?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, runtime

I've seen a couple .net applications that allow you to select a C# .cs source file and the program itself will compile this code and run it.

How is this done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It probably uses the CSharpCodeProvider class in the Microsoft.CSharp namespace.  You would want to look at the following methods to compile code:

```
CompileAssemblyFromDom
CompileAssemblyFromFile
CompileAssemblyFromSource
```

Answer (score 2):

[CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx) is your friend

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a great series of articles explaining this...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My guess is by explicitly calling the csc.exe compiler.  Keep in mind that this and any dependencies would have to be included with your deployment.

You can take a look at [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/) which interprets C# files.  Its free but not open sources though...